# How can I close an autocomplete menu after 10 seconds regardless of where the cursor or focus is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a JQuery UI autocomplete function and want the menu to stay open for 10 seconds, regardless of where the focus is. I have:

```
$("#term").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://example.com/",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        q: request.term
      },
      success: function(data) {
        response(data);
      }
    });
  },
  close: function() {
    $('.ui-autocomplete').show().delay(10000).hide();
  }  
});
```

This, unfortunately, makes it so it closes immediately once the ac area loses focus. If I remove the `.delay(10000).hide()` part it stays open indefinitely but I need to close it after a few seconds. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using a `setTimeout()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $("#term").autocomplete( "disable" );
}, 10000);
```